Append slug of each blog post with a hash based on a custom field
I have a lots of blog posts on my blog, now I am creating some content for a cluster of keywords, I need a way to track the traffic of those pages with simple filter.
One way that I can think off is to append a hash(from custom field) to the slug of these posts something like example.com/blog/my-interesting-blog-post-a23fac5s where a23fac5s comes from a custom field.
This way I can filter all the posts with this hash a23fac5s in Google Analytics and track the performance.
Please suggest if there are better ways as well.
